# Open CV error in motion detection

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

## OpenCV Python program to detect cars in video frame

## import libraries of python OpenCV

import cv2

## capture frames from a video

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

## Trained XML classifiers describes some features of some object we want to detect

car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')

## loop runs if capturing has been initialized.

while True:
    # reads frames from a video
    ret, frames = cap.read()

```
# convert to gray scale of each frames
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


*[
```

## Detects cars of different sizes in the input image

```
cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 1)

# To draw a rectangle in each cars
for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
    cv2.rectangle(frames,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
 # Display frames in a window
```

][1]* 
        cv2.imshow('video2', frames)

```
# Wait for Esc key to stop
if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
    break
```

## De-allocate any associated memory usage

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

source : https://github.com/shaanhk/New-GithubTest
 error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/python/abc/detection/detect.py", line 9, in 
    car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:2754: error: (-212) cars.xml(2): Attribute name should be followed by '=' in function icvXMLParseTag

No answers I found till now help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code is where your error pops up from. I have taken this from persistence.cpp. I think it may be a problem with your xml file itself.

```
if( *ptr != '=' )
                {
                    ptr = icvXMLSkipSpaces( fs, ptr, CV_XML_INSIDE_TAG );
                    if( *ptr != '=' )
                        CV_PARSE_ERROR( "Attribute name should be followed by \'=\'" );
}
```